# Django URL keeps being longer

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am new to django and I am working on url redirects. On my views I am using HttpResponseRedirect and render functions to switch views.

The problem is after couple of switching around between views, the URL keeps getting longer. Here is the URL on the chrome after I switched between addcostumer and delete costumer views

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/interface/addcostumer/deletecostumer/addcostumer/deletecostumer/preview/preview/addcostumer/deletecostumer/
```

How do I make the URL just

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/interface/addcostumer/
```

when I am in addcostumer view and

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/interface/deletecostumer/
```

when I am  in deletecostumer view

insted of them being appended one after another whenever I switch between views.

```
class AddCostumerView(FirstPageView):

def __init__(self):
    super()
    self.main_template = "addcostumer.html"

def get(self, request):
    form = CostumerForm()
    return render(request, template_name=self.base_template,
                  context={"company_list": list(database.get_companies()),
                           "sister_page": self.main_template,
                           "form": form})

@method_decorator(csrf_protect)
def post(self, request):
    print("this line is running now")
    form = CostumerForm(request.POST)

    if request.FILES["myfile"]:
        myfile = request.FILES["myfile"]
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)


    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        #database.add_costumer(**data)

        #preview the data and preview the file

        #Add for final submission
        #messages.success(request, filename)

        return HttpResponseRedirect("preview/")  # TODO change to proper page
    return HttpResponseRedirect("firstpage.html")


class DeleteCostumerView(FirstPageView):

def __int__(self):
    super()
    self.main_template = "deletecostumer.html"

def get(self, request):
    companies = database.get_companies()

    print("delete get request")

    return render(request, template_name= self.base_template,
                  context={
                      "company_list": companies,
                      "sister_page" : "deletecostumer.html",
                      "form": DeleteForm(),
                  })

def post(self, request):

    submission = request.POST
    form = DeleteForm(submission)

    if form.is_valid():
        companyID = form.cleaned_data["company"]

        database.delete_costumer(**{"companyID":companyID})
        return HttpResponseRedirect("deleteconstumer.html")

    return HttpResponseRedirect("deleteconstumer.html")
```

Comment: Maybe you should post the code where you are using that redirect?

Comment: I added the code for the views.

Comment: Why are you using text for the redirect and the .html why not use `reverse` with the url name?

Comment: I could not properly understand `reverse` when reading the documentation. Now I think I understand it better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HttpResponseRedirect("preview/")` is a relative path and will always be appended to the path from which you execute this code, either use an absolute path like `'/preview/'` or better use Djangos [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/) utility function for constructing your redirects.

Comment: I'd say use the `redirect` shortcut with the view name, it does the `reverse` for you, but that's just a convenience thing. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect